# APPSHEET move entire data to first row when data is updated/added

Tags: google-sheets, google-appsheet

In my google sheet, I created a script that everytime a new data added or edited it will automically move it to the first row in my google sheet. What I want is when everytime I update a data or add a new data using the Appsheet, it will also automatically move it to the first row in my google sheet data

Answer (score 0):

It's common when people are first starting to integrate AppSheet into their workflows, that they still rely on their spreadsheet as their primary interface.

You might consider changing where you're doing the bulk of your user interaction, changing it from the spreadsheet into AppSheet itself.

Inside AppSheet, you can easily sort the views of your sheet, basing everything off of a timestamp - so the most recently updated record is always visible at the top of the table

Doing it this way means you're just displaying your data, you're not actually modifying the data.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).